# How do I wrap this jQuery call in a function so I can reuse it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Take this example where I'm trying to wrap a jQuery AJAX call for reuse:

```
function do_ajax(url, data) {
    return $.ajax(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        data: data,
        headers: {
            Authorization: auth_header
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}

do_ajax('/my_url', { stuff: 'here' }).done(function(response) {
    console.log('response');
});
```

As I understand it, this should work. Why doesn't it? I thought `$.ajax` was a function itself and could therefore be returned by my enclosing function. Can anyone clever explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What you have should work fine. Check the console for errors

Comment: Any error that you're receiving in console?

Comment: You can always put `debugger` just before `do_ajax` call, and check what is actually being returned.

If that fails - check does request is being perfomed (network tab in dev tools).

Comment: the code is working find for me when i define the var auth_header='' before return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the variable `auth_header` is not defined in the scope where you define the `do_ajax` function but it was defined in the scope where your trying to call `do_ajax` from. That would explain why `$.ajax` works inline but not when called via `do_ajax`.

try changing

```
function do_ajax(url, data) {
```

to

```
function do_ajax(url, data, auth_header) {
```

and also change

```
do_ajax('/my_url', { stuff: 'here' }).done(function(response) {
```

to

```
do_ajax('/my_url', { stuff: 'here' }, auth_header).done(function(response) {
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
function do_ajax(url, data) {
    return $.ajax({
        url:url,
        method: 'GET',
        data: data,
        headers: {Authorization: auth_header},
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}

do_ajax('/my_url', { stuff: 'here' }).done(function(response) {
    console.log('response');
});
```

Comment: you just used the $.ajax in bad way. you passed parameters in bad way . $.ajax accept a javascript Object which you pass every thins as property in that Object ..

Comment: Wrong.  You can pass the url as the 1st parameter and the settings as the 2nd.  Check the documentation... http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @Archer it's not wrong . please read carefully what i tell about $.ajax ....                                      this is wrong =====> $.ajax(url,{options  })   and this one is correct  =====> $.ajax({ options  including URL   })

Comment: `$.ajax(url, { options });` is fine - read the documentation I gave you a link for.  It's the very first example of using `$.ajax()`

Comment: Yes you are right . 1st url and options object  is ok